# Illegal character in javascript string parameter coming from SQL

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm maintaining an asp.net rest api where SQL data is loaded trough stored procedures and converted to rest.

On the web page I have an html element with an onclick attribute passing in the content of a result as a parameter. This works fine for almost all occurrences, but one gives an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in the chrome console.

I'm expecting that this character in the string is the issue:

```
↵
```

I just can't find out what character I need to replace in C# to remove this from the string. And I don't have a good environment to test or debug this.

Ps altering the stored procedure in SQL is not an option.

-- update --

I can't give the exact values as this is a bit confidential, but this is returned form the rest api when I inspect it with chrome (the result of the api call in the network tab):

```
21.12.15 xxx xxx xxx
↵
↵[xxx 13-01-2016] gebeld, gesproken met xxx : hij heeft met xxx besproken dat
```

I have an info icon with an onclick event passing in the string above (PayComment) as parameter. {{PayComment}} is replaced by handlebars with the string above.

```
<span onclick="GetInvoicePayComment('{{PayComment}}');">i</span>
```

I've set a debugger on the first line of the javascript function but it never reaches that line.

```
function GetInvoicePayComment(Comment) {
//
}
```

-- update 2 --
With the discussions here I thought I needed to check the source html as handlebars replaces the {{PayComment}} with the value. The result looks like this:

```
<span class="small fa fa-info-circle" style="text-align: center; font-size: 18px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="GetInvoicePayComment('21.12.15 xxxx

[xxxx 13-01-2016] gebeld, gesproken met xxx : hij heeft met Rxxx besproken dat deze factuur nog niet moet worden betaald.');"></span>
```

I'm guessing the newline here is the issue and not the characters.

Comment: Probably your procedure result contains a new line literal and that causes browser that issue. If you can provide more information about issue (an example output and exact issue on your browser), I can help you more efficient way.

Comment: What kind of data does GetInvoicePayComment('{{PayComment}}'); fetchs ? I mean the issue you are facing depends on your data type. I assume you are fetching that data via ajax call and If your ajax data type is javascript newline literal can cause that issue. ↵ this is just a unicode character and your issue should not related with that character.

Comment: The page loads the data form the rest api with handlebars. The {{PayComment}} is already loaded, I just don't show it in the interface. When the user clicks the i icon, I show a popup with the {{PayComment}} contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by removing the newline in the api:

```
PayComment = item.PayComment.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can eleminate return character in str string like that:

```
str.replace("↵", "");
```

or you can preferably replace it with new line chars like that:

```
str.replace("↵", "\n");
str.replace("↵", "<br>");
```

Comment: In javascript or c#? And can you just replace that character as is? When I look at the sql source I can't see the character. I'm guessing it's char(13) and char(10) in the sql source, but don't know how to be sure.

Comment: yes, javascript do has string.replace() method. For the char you can check the return string value in developer debug console. For test, you can fire the function just running it from between <script></script> tags instead of firing an event